# Find missing records in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following database table

tbl_setup

```
id
peer
gw
```

I have the following records in there

```
1 | HA | GW1
2 | HA | GW2
3 | HA | GW3
4 | AA | GW1
5 | AB | GW2
6 | AB | GW3
7 | AB | GW4
8 | EE | GW3
```

Trying to figure out a query to find out which GW are missing data so trying to figure out a query to give me the following results, these would be the GW's missing

```
HA | GW4
AA | GW2
AA | GW3
AA | GW4
AB | GW1
EE | GW1
EE | GW2
EE | GW4
```

There should only be 4 GW's GW1 - GW4, will never be more than that

Comment: Please confirm master data for `peer` and `gw` column.

Comment: The data that you are seeing in the first code block is what is in there now, and i just need to be able to run a query to see whats missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `cross join` of the `distinct` values of the 2 columns and then `not exists`:

```
select *
from (select distinct gw from tablename) g 
cross join (select distinct peer from tablename) p 
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where gw = g.gw and peer = p.peer
)
order by gw, peer
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mGFJCLKoGW84DiegwHf3Fy/0).
Or:

```
select g.gw, p.peer
from (select distinct gw from tablename) g 
cross join (select distinct peer from tablename) p 
left join tablename t
on t.gw = g.gw and t.peer = p.peer
where t.id is null
order by g.gw, p.peer
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gtqcBK2kQez33qMxYxZRGL/0).
Results:

```
| gw  | peer |
| --- | ---- |
| AA  | GW2  |
| AA  | GW3  |
| AA  | GW4  |
| AB  | GW1  |
| EE  | GW1  |
| EE  | GW2  |
| EE  | GW4  |
| HA  | GW4  |
```

Comment: Arr, you beat me to it ;) Was going to suggest the same with Minus

Comment: That was perfect, thank you sooo much, exactly what i needed. Just curious though what exactly does this line "where t.id is null" , i don't it would ever see a null value there since the id's are auto-increment, and they would never be null

Comment: This code joins all the possible combinations of gw and peer to the table. What you want is the **non matching** pairs because the matching exist in the table. These are the rows with id is null.

Comment: This does not mean that there are nulls in the column id. Just that there is not such an id.

Comment: Ohh ok i understand now, thank you very much for the explanation, and i just accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to do a `cross join` to get all the rows and then filter out the ones that exist.  There are several ways to do the filtering.  I usually use `left join`, although `not exists,`not in`, and`except` are all reasonable alternatives.

If all the peers and gws are in the original table, then you can use that.  However, you suggests that there is a separate list, at least for the `gw` values.  You can list those explicitly:

```
select p.peer, g.gw
from (select distinct peer from t) p cross join
     (values ('GW1'), ('GW2'), ('GW3'), ('GW4')) g(gw) left join
     t
     on t.peer = p.peer and t.gw = g.gw
where t.peer is null;
```